# NMaximize computes wrong value

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, numerical-value, maximum

This question is a continuation of [NIntegrate with a complicated function over the 4-sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253638/nintegrate-with-a-complicated-function-over-the-4-sphere) . Now I define a certain new function called "improvement" via:

```
improvement[a_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), b_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), 
  c_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), d_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
 terma[a, b, c, d] + termd[d, a, b, c] + termc[c, d, a, b] + 
  termb[b, c, d, a]
```

where `terma`, `termb`, `termc`, `termd` are defined as in the previous question (now using hypershperical coordinates to integrate over the sphere). The parameters $(a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb{S}^{63}$ belong to the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{64}$. The function `improvement` returns some reasonable values when evaluated on random points on $\mathbb{S}^{63}$, such as:
[image: ![enter image description here]
It takes about $20$ seconds to evaluate the `improvement` on one value. (I will ignore the fact that the integral "fails to converge", as the returned values are within the expected range.) This means that the function `improvement` works and returns good values.

When I run NMaximize on `improvement` (here $d = 16$):

```
NMaximize[improvement[R[[1 ;; d]], R[[d + 1 ;; 2*d]], R[[2*d + 1 ;; 3*d]], 
  R[[3*d + 1 ;; 4*d]]], R \[Element] Sphere[4*d]]
```

[image]
and it keeps running forever. The main problem is that the values that are returned by NIntegrate are now **completely wrong**, i.e. they should be between $20$ and $30$, as in the previous image (there `terma` returned 21.62...). **How to fix this?** Why does running `NMaximize` make `improvement` return wrong values?

Also, is it reasonable to expect that `NMaximize` can actually determine the maximal value of my functional in finite time?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `NMaximize` won't succeed if you cannot compute your function.  Fix that before focusing attention on `NMaximize`.

Comment: I can compute my function and this is what I tried to explain. The fact that NIntegrate failed to converge is not presently an issue. The issue is that running NMaximize causes improvement to return the wrong values, MUCH different than those that it returns if I run it on just one value of the parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: "I can compute my function...NIntegrate failed to converge..." seems a contradiction, since it seems `improvement[]` calls `NIntegrate`, unless a bad result from `NIntegrate` is irrelevant, which seems unlikely to me.

Comment: It's not completely irrelevant, but it is secondary. I got "..NIntegrate obtained 24.64... and 0.206... for the integral and error estimates.", which means that NIntegrate did return a value, and it is within the reasonable interval I expect for the function to return. The problem is that later, when I run NMaximize, it returns (as you can see in the image), "...NIntegrate obtained 241.152... and 1.966... for the integral and error estimates." This value is approximately 10 times larger than what I had obtained previously, and this doesn't make any sense.